# Custom control has reference to datatable but is not updating across threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a custom control that I created and it was working when everything was single thread.  It does update with the first message before I send it off to the interface.

I have a datatable:

```
            DataTable dtNew = new DataTable(szTableName);  // to add into a dataset later
            dtNew.Columns.Add("EventDate",typeof(string));
            dtNew.Columns.Add("Function",typeof(string));
            dtNew.Columns.Add("IsError",typeof(bool));
            dtNew.Columns.Add("LongMessage",typeof(string));
            dtNew.Columns.Add("Message",typeof(string));
            dtNew.Columns.Add("Process",typeof(string));
            dtNew.Columns.Add("RecID",typeof(string));
            dtNew.Columns.Add("Thread",typeof(string));
            dtNew.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
            ProcessStatus NewPanel = new ProcessStatus(); // create custom control
            NewPanel.SetDataSource(ref dtNew); // sets the datasource to the datatable
            dsLogs.Tables.Add(dtNew); // add datatable into dataset
```

Custom control receives the datasource so it should be bound:

```
public partial class ProcessStatus : UserControl
{

    public ProcessStatus()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void SetProcess(string szProcName)
    {
        lblProcess.Text = "Process: " + szProcName;
    }

    public void SetThread(string szThreadName)
    {
        lblThreadNum.Text = "Thread: " + szThreadName;
    }

    public void SetDataSource(ref DataTable dtTable)
    {
        dgvProcess.DataSource = dtTable;

        dgvProcess.Columns["EventDate"].Visible = false;
        //dgvProcess.Columns["Function"].Visible = false;
        dgvProcess.Columns["IsError"].Visible = false;
        dgvProcess.Columns["LongMessage"].Visible = false;
        //dgvProcess.Columns["Message"].Visible = false;
        dgvProcess.Columns["Process"].Visible = false;
        dgvProcess.Columns["RecID"].Visible = false;
        dgvProcess.Columns["Thread"].Visible = false;
        dgvProcess.Columns["UserName"].Visible = false;
        dgvProcess.Columns["Function"].Width = 80;
        dgvProcess.Columns["Message"].Width = 200;
    }

    // only show first line
    private void dgvProcess_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvProcess.RowCount > 0)
            dgvProcess.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvProcess.RowCount - 1;
    }

}
```

When the datatable is updated with a new message, that message is not updated in the custom control (in the datagrid).  Again, this did work on single thread so I'm probably not doing something right to allow this to update crossthreads or something like that...

Comment: There is no multithreaded code in your example

Comment: If `datagrid` is a webforms `DataGrid` or `GridView` it's a single thread. Is something in your custom control, `static`?

Comment: No static, I just added in the whole class for the custom control (I'm using a datagridview)

Comment: @DaBlue Your sample code does not use threading. I guess it is the working pre-multithread version, but we can't fix working code.

Comment: Adding in the multithread stuff on here sounds easy enough, problem is that its quite large...  Anyway, Tim Schmelter pointed me in the right direction.  After much reading, it became apparent that those controls probably wouldn't work well in a multithreaded environment (still would like to know why though).  I changed the logic to get rid of the datagridview and replaced it with a textbox which is being updated through a delegate.  Thanks for the pointer, Tim.